# Append is not a function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

In the following code, I'd like to be able to append `test_div` to the element that was clicked on.  However, I get the error message that `TypeError:`e.srcElement.append`is not a function`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    onclick = function (e) {
        var test_div = document.createElement("div");
        target = e.srcElement
        target.append(test_div);
        }

    $('#dialogue').on('click', onclick);

});
```

I've tried printing out the type of `e.srcElement`, but it just says `object`, which isn't very helpful.  What's the correct way to append an element to the item clicked on?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`.append()` is jquery method. You need to convert DOM object into jquery object for using jquery methods:

```
 $(target).append(test_div);
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, the javascript method you can use is `appendChild()`

`target.appendChild(test_div);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use jQuery for this. Moreover, you are mixing vanilla JavaScript and jQuery. An alternate way of doing this is:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#dialogue').on('click', function (e) {
    var test_div = $("<div />");
    $(this).append(test_div);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

`e.srcElement` is a DOM node. The correct method to append another element in to it is `appendChild`

`.append` is the equivalent JQuery method.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) is the documentation

---

*"I've tried printing out the type of `e.srcElement`, but it just says `object`"*

`console.log()` your debug messages.